# JavaScript: Different behavior when using dot-notation vs. bracket-notation

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript snippet

```
var x = window.foo;
window.x = null;
alert( window.bar === undefined );
```

alerts "true".

However, this snippet

```
var x = window.foo;
window[x] = null;
alert( window.bar === undefined );
```

alerts "false".

What is going on here?

(I am running this code in the latest Chrome browser inside a HTML page with no other JavaScript code in it.)

***Update***

As @elusive cleverly summed up in his comment below, I mistakingly assumed that `window.x` and `window[x]` are equivalent. That is not correct. `window.x` is equivalent to `window["x"]`.

Comment: May we ask what the content of `window.foo` is?

Comment: `window.x` is equivalent to `window['x']` not `window[x]`.

Comment: @elusive Yes, you summed it up into one sentence :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior that you are experiencing is because the `undefined` property of the Global object, is mutable on any *ECMAScript 3* based implementation. (latest Chrome versions are implementing ES5, but this behavior is still present).

Let's examine the second snippet:

```
var x = window.foo;
window[x] = null;
alert( window.bar === undefined );
```

The `x` variable will hold the `undefined` value, since the `foo` property does not exist.

By assigning `window[x] = null`, you are overriding the value of the `undefined` property:

```
window[x] = null; // is equivalent to
window['undefined'] = null; // or
window.undefined = null; //
```

(In your first snippet, when you assign `window.x = null`, you are creating a property named `"x"` on the `window` object.)

Therefore (in your second snippet), the `undefined` property will hold `null`, and `window.bar` will produce `undefined`:

```
alert( window.bar === undefined ); // false
alert( undefined  === null ); // false
```

The `undefined` property was not specified as `{ ReadOnly }` on ECMAScript 3, (along with his friends `NaN`, `Infinity`).

This has changed in ECMAScript 5, those properties are described as non-writables.

Comment: @CMS Isn't the `undefined` global property mutable on any browser, not just Chrome?

Comment: @Šime, it *should* be mutable on any *ES3-based implementation*. From the latest browser versions that I have tested (Firefox, WebKit, IE9, Chrome), Chrome is the only one that still has `undefined` as writable, even on Chrome 9.0.583.0.

Comment: @CMS These are not the results that I'm getting. The latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera allow me to change the value of the `undefined` global property. Only IE9 beta and Safari don't allow it.

Comment: FWIW, jQuery is wrapped in `(function(window, undefined) { ... })(window)`, which ensures that `undefined` actually does have its correct value.

Comment: @Šime by *latest versions* I meant **nightly builds**, *Firefox 4Beta8 Pre*, *Chrome 9.0.583.0*, *WebKit r72284*, etc... they do implement a lot of ES5, Firefox and Webkit are finishing strict-mode support :)

Comment: @CMS Aha, those latest builds implement ES5 and therefore don't allow `undefined` to be changed. However, it is strange that Chrome 9 does allow it. Hey, can you do me a favor? Can you go to http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/strict-mode/ in Chrome 9 and check out how it handles the strict mode rules. I would love to know that :)

Comment: @Šime, Chrome 9 doesn't implement strict mode **at all**, just like IE9... too bad, all red :(. If you want to play with strict mode, get the latest WebKit and Firefox :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = window.foo;  // set the local variable x to the contents of window.foo
window.x = null; // set property x on window to null
```

Here you're directly setting the propery `x` to null.

```
var x = window.foo; // set the local variable x to the contents of window.foo
window[x] = null; // set they key with the value of x to null
```

Here you're setting a property by using it as a `key` on the window object. Which key is that? Well that depends on the value of `x`, if `x` is `bar` you will effectively do `window.bar = null` if `x` is `blub` you'll do `window.blub = null`.

For more information on this you should head over to MDC:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Comment: Actually, this is global code, so x is a global variable.

Comment: The answer is the same. window.x sets the property named 'x'. window[x] sets the property named 'value-of-global-variable-x'.