# Javascript add an object into object array

Tags: javascript

Example -

```
var users = {

};

var conn = "ajey";

var ajey = {
  name: 'ajey',
  age: 25
}

users.conn = ajey;
```

This returns

```
[object Object] {
  conn: [object Object] {
    age: 25,
    name: "ajey"
  }
}
```

As you notice the object key is "conn" but how do I make it substitute the value of `conn`
which is "ajey" ??

[JS bin here](http://jsbin.com/kijoyi/1/edit)

**NOTE - I am not trying to access the object key. I am trying to set the object key with the value of a variable**

Comment: Look for "bracket notation"

Comment: @elclanrs: I am not trying to access the object key. I am trying to set the object key with the value of an existing variable

Comment: @elclanrs How is it a duplicate question?

Comment: It's about bracket notation, extrapolate... More dups, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189642/difference-between-using-bracket-and-dot-notation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234777/javascript-different-behavior-when-using-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation